# Is the word "Ray" related to the Egyptian "Ra"

Tags: etymology

My Communications professor was quite adamant that the word "radio" could be traced back to the Egyptian word for sun, "ra". Radio comes from the Latin "radius" and I could find no sources that connected radius to ra. In fact, I'm pretty sure that Latin didn't develop out of Egyptian at all, but I could be mistaken. Can anyone offer further insight?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question title asks about *ray*, but your text asks about *radius*; which is it? We can better help if you indicate which dictionaries or other sources you have already consulted. I also encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.

Comment: It may be or it may not be. The question is how to verify wandering of words from  the Egyptian or Semitic area into Greek or Latin or Sanskrit. Certainly there are hardly any instances to be found that could verify such assumptions. So a statement that radio derives from Ra is a wild guess that can't be verified. Certainly, we may assume that Semitic words wandered into IE languages, the problem is how to prove it.

Answer (score 6):

Ra was the Egyptian Sun god. His name was not spelled *Ra*, as the language was hieroglyphic Egyptian and various forms of Demotic Egyptian, which didn't have our letters.

*Ray* comes to English through Old French *rai*, from Latin *radius* (spoke).

There is no evidence that the sun *ray* comes from Ra - there are entirely different languages between them.

Comment: I see no problem with Latin or any other old language accepting loan words from ancient Egyptian. Why should they not have? The fact that Egyptian is hieroglyphically written is not relevant. Loan words are more than likely accepted in spoken form and then absorbed into and adapted by the local forms of speech and spelling. Clearly, it does not matter that Egyptian is not IE. English happily accepts words from non-IE languages (eg, 'kiosk' from Turkish or. 'Juju' from a southern African language). Is 'ray' derived from 'ra'? Could be.... The similarity is intriguing, for sure. But we just don'

Answer (score -1):

It's more likely that it evolved from the Sanskrit roots [*Surya*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya) सूर्य Sūrya, "the Supreme Light" or *Ravi*, the chief solar deity in Hinduism (generally,) the Sun.

Comment: Is it possible that the Sanskrit 'ravi' and the Egyptian 'ra/re' share proto-Indoeuropean roots?

Comment: No. Egyptian is not Indo-European,

Comment: OED says *cassical Latin radius, of uncertain origin*.  Probably we should not say that the Latin came from Sanskrit, but that both came from a common ancestor language.

Comment: @GEdgar "we should not say that the Latin came from Sanskrit:" Why?

Comment: @Kris: Perhaps that is a question for linguistics, not English.